How to publish data to a topic different than the one listened to
I want to execute a ROS2 command say:
ros2 topic pub --smth /obj std_msgs/String "sometext"

from a package node (written in Python) that is execute using the command such as :
ros2 run somepck somefunc

That is publishing data to a topic from a listener node that is listening to a different topic from whee the data are received.
How to do that in Python?
can the MinimalPublisher class ( from here: https://ros2-industrial-workshop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_source/basics/ROS2-Simple-Publisher-Subscriber.html) be edited to change the name of the topic and be used in this case?

On your subscriber node, you can also create a publisher. Lets take an example from the minimal_subscriber:
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__('minimal_subscriber')
    self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
        String,
        'topic',
        self.listener_callback,
        10)
    self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)

And then create a listener_callback function that has a publish function:
def listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data)
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)


ok, but the problem is that I have to launch a script before being able to publish at the second topic named 'topic' here as follows;
ros2 launch somepackage something.launch.py
do I have to execute the launch command in the same terminal where the current node code (with your solution) is being executed? or that ROS will know where to look for the 'other' topic?

also the listener and publisher topics I tought they should be the same! as I want to listen to a topic and publish in another!
